# ios paper app: swipe from off screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I am studying Paper App from Fifty Three and find it very interesting the way they used for various gesture.

To differentiate the gesture from the PAN that they use for drawing, to turn the pages, you need to swipe from off the screen(as in outside of iPad screen) into the view to work.

How to implement that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to Paper's code, but I would guess they are using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` **only along the sides**. Since the recognized 'captures' the touch, it wouldn't trigger their main drawing mechanism, but would catch only slides from offscreen - it might be only about 10-20pts wide.